# Does Chromecast support few media streams playing in parallel?

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast

Does Chromecast support few media streams playing in parallel?
For instance, one stream is youtube video and another stream is audio playback?

UPD: maybe word "stream" is not correct in this case, I mean media file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There can be at most one active Media element on the page. For Audio, if you want to play multiple tracks simultaneously, you can use Web Audio APIs but that has a limitation that it cannot be stream (i.e. it downloads them and then play, so it stays in memory, hence can't be too long).